# Getting error: "Matrix do not have a method or closure named..."

Tags: templating, matrix

I just playing first time with Matrix and can't figure whats wrong with this code, here's error code:

```
Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "naglowekPowitanie".
```

Matrix field config:
[image: config]

```
{% for block in entry.homepage %}
        {% if block.type == "powitanie" %}
            <article id="main">

                <header class="special container">
                    <span class="icon fa-truck"></span>
                    <h2>{{ block.naglowekPowitanie }}</h2>
                    <p>{{ block.trescPowitanie }}</p>
                </header>

        {% elseif block.type == "wstep" %}
                    <section class="wrapper style2 container special-alt">
                        <div class="row 50%">
                            <div class="8u 12u(narrower)">

                                <header>
                                    <h2>{{ block.wstepNaglowek }}</h2>
                                </header>
                                <p>{{ block.wstepTresc }}</p>
                                <footer>
                                    <ul class="buttons">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="button">{{ block.wstepPrzycisk }}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </footer>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

On your screenshot of the block type powitanie you see two fields: `powitanieNaglowek` and `powitanieTresc`. Yet, in your code you try to use

```
  <h2>{{ block.naglowekPowitanie }}</h2>
```

The error simply says: in the block type you are using there is no field called `naglowekPowitanie`.

Changing that H2 to

```
  <h2>{{ block.powitanieNaglowek }}</h2>
```

should do the trick.